# Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `method group' and `float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following BurgZergArcade Tutorial on how to create a Hack'N'Slash game. During that I have encountered an error and I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me. The language is c#.

Error: Assets/Scripts/Character Classes/ModifiedStat.cs(21,66): error CS0019: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type`method group' and `float'

```
public class BaseStat {
    public class BaseStat {
    private int _baseValue;         //The base value of this stat
    private int _buffValue;         //The amount of buff to this stat
    private int _expToLevel;        //Thetotal amount of exp needed to raise this skill
    private float _levelModifier;   //The modifier applied to the exp needed to raise the skill

    public BaseStat() {
        _baseValue = 0;
        _buffValue = 0;
        _levelModifier = 1.1f;
        _expToLevel = 100;
    }

    public int BaseValue{
        get{ return _baseValue; }
        set{ _baseValue = value; }
    }
    public int BuffValue{
        get{ return _buffValue; }
        set{ _buffValue = value; }
    }
    public int ExpToLevel{
        get{ return _expToLevel; }
        set{ _expToLevel = value; }
    }
    public float LevelModifier{
        get{ return _levelModifier; }
        set{ _levelModifier = value; }
    }

    private int CalculateExpToLevel() {
        return (int)(_expToLevel * _levelModifier);
    }
    public void LevelUp() {
        _expToLevel = CalculateExpToLevel();
        _baseValue++;
    }
    public int AdjustedValue() {
        return _baseValue + _buffValue;
    }
}

public class Atrribute : BaseStat {
    public Atrribute() {
        ExpToLevel = 50;
        LevelModifier = 1.05f;
    }
}

public enum AttributeName{
Might,
Constitution,
Nimbleness,
Speed,
Concentration,
Willpower,
Charisma
}

public class ModifiedStat : BaseStat {
    private List<ModifyingAttribute> _mods;         //A list of Attributes that modify this stat
    private int _modValue;                          //

    public ModifiedStat(){
        _mods = new List<ModifyingAttribute>();
        _modValue = 0;
    }

    public void AddModifier( ModifyingAttribute mod ) {
        _mods.Add(mod);
    }

    private void CalculateModValue() {
        _modValue = 0;

        if(_mods.Count > 0)
            foreach( ModifyingAttribute att in _mods )
                _modValue += (int)(att.attribute.AdjustedValue * att.ratio);
    }
}

public struct ModifyingAttribute {
    public Atrribute attribute;
    public float ratio;
}
```

Comment: Messages along those lines almost always indicate you forgot the parentheses after a method name when calling it.

Comment: As an aside, consider using implicitly implemented properties and backing fields, as that will significantly clean up your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `BaseState.AdjustedValue` is a method, I would change the line in `ModifiedStat.CalculateModValue()` to:

```
_modValue += (int)(att.attribute.AdjustedValue() * att.ratio);
```

Please note the `()` after `AdjustedValue`.

Comment: @Maarten I am getting the same error with this line of code   `bPointP0 = points [2] + (Vector3.Lerp (points [0], reflectedCp1, t) - points [2]).Normalize * (points [0] - points [2]).magnitude;`